# « Je suis le seul qui a(i) un problème »

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison

Je rencontre un problème quand j'essaie d'utiliser un jeu sur mon téléphone.

J'ai posé cette question dans le forum mais je ne suis pas sûr qu'elle soit correcte:

> Est-ce que je suis le seul qui a un souci avec son compte MarMon (le jeu)

À un moment je voulais reformuler de la manière suivante:

> Est-ce que je suis le seul qui ai un souci avec mon compte MarMon (le jeu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La première forme me semble la plus correcte, mais, pour éviter tout risque d'accord dissonant, j'écrirais plutôt :

> Est-ce que je suis le seul à avoir un souci avec mon compte MarMon ?

ou :

> Est-ce que d'autres joueurs ont des soucis avec leurs comptes MarMon ?

voire le plus recherché :

> Suis-je le seul à avoir un souci avec mon compte MarMon ?

Le problème si l'on utilise la première personne est que la phrase ne peut plus être découpée en deux parties avec *est-ce que je suis* d'un côté et le reste de l'autre, la deuxième partie devient agrammaticale :

> *le seul qui ai un souci...

En remplaçant *le seul* par *celui*, on sent encore plus l'incohérence:

> *Suis-je celui qui ai un souci...

Comment: Pourriez-vous m'expliquer la raison pour laquelle ma première phrase est bonne mais pas la deuxième?

Comment: Je me le demande aussi ;-) Je me suis peut-être avancé un peu vite. L'indicatif, le subjonctif et le conditionnel sont peut-être tous trois possibles, ainsi que l'accord avec l'un ou l'autre sujet. Dans le doute, je préfère conseiller l'infinitif !

Comment: D'accord. Par contre je n'ai utilisé que l'indicatif dans mes deux phrase interrogatives

Comment: La deuxième phrase doit être en fait acceptable, tout comme *suis-je le seul qui aie...* et *suis-je le seul qui ait...*.

Answer (score 2):

La première phrase est la correcte. Derrière qui, l'accord se fait avec l'antécédent, c'est-à-dire avec le mot représenté par qui.

> C'est moi qui ai...C'est celui qui a...etc.
>
> C'est toi qui étais chargé des courses.
>
> Tu es **le seul qui pouvait** les porter.
>
> Vous qui avez de l'argent (Balzac).
>
> C'est moi qui fais tout.

[Référence: Optimiser son score au certificat Voltaire. M.F. Claerebout.](https://www.amazon.fr/Optimiser-son-score-certificat-Voltaire/dp/2130786014/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_14_t_0?_encoding=UTF8&psc=1&refRID=AVBMGMS3YDYEAEP2Y0RK)

Comment: Mais ne peut-on pas utiliser "Est-ce que je suis le seul qui ait un souci" ? Cela expliquerait pourquoi la seconde forme ne choque pas mes oreilles...